# Should a data constant needed for validation exist in a domain entity or database stored procedure

Tags: c#, validation, stored-procedures, domain-driven-design, n-layer

I have a business rule to validate in a domain layer for an Order entity.  The rule is a requesting customer must of had an account with the store for at least 30 days to qualify for a certain discount. The value of 30 can be defined as a constant in the Order Entity of the Domain Layer or as part of a stored procedure where it is defined as a constant and returned when invoked by an Application Service then passed to a Domain Entity for rules validation?

If it is in a stored procedure then I can change the number in the database and recompile the stored procedure, which is very easy to do with little involvement to others.  But if I put it in the Entity it becomes part of the application code which not only needs recompiling but redistribution.

Where are these kind of number constants being stored for N-Layer design applications trying to implement a DDD design?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it belongs in the domain :)

Well, an interface defined in your domain in the same way that one defines repositories.  The implementation can be anywhere and even include some default implementation included in the domain.

In your example your discount condition is rather simple.  However, what about scenarios where your discount percentage determination is more complex?  One would not want that in a stored procedure as testing would be more difficult.  Let's assume one *does* place it in the stored procedure.  What happens when you have multiple clients using your program that each require a different number of days.

The point is that you need to determine, along with your domain experts, how one could configure and design the rules to make it as flexible as is required.  If, for example, you only need to vary the day then you could have that as some configurable setting in your system.

However, you probably want something that follows the strategy pattern.  Come to think of it, most of a system would be the strategy pattern :)

Anyway, how about the following (or anything that makes sense in you scenario):

```
public interface IDiscountService
{
    float GetDiscount(Customer customer, Order order);
}
```

In the implementation your could have an `IDiscountConfiguration` injected that provides the number of days, wherever they may need to be retrieved from (app.config, web-service, xml, database).

Uses this mechanism you could alter how the discount is determined at any point without reliance on a particular implementation.  You could go as far as to have the implementation differ for each client and simply instantiate the relevant discount calculator for the environment you are in.

Also, testing the various services becomes a breeze as you `new` up an instance in your unit test and test away.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Multiple clients would have their own account activation date. The rule is a client has to of had an account for some min number of days. The domain uses the account activation date to calculate if the client has been active for more than the min days value returned from the stored procedure (i.e. 30 days). I'll lookup the strategy pattern you suggested. Sounds like you are saying to inject a service that returns the defined min days so the implementation can be provided from more than a stored procedure.

Comment: That's correct.  All this can usually be performed by a Stored Procedure but that is all the way back to a data-driven approach so definitely not DDD :)